# How to convert blob data into an image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm trying to transfer an image through a WebSocket and then display it on a webpage. Image is sent as a blob.

```
websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
    document.getElementById("foto").src = "data:image/png;event.data)";
};
```

I'm getting this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
document.getElementById("foto").src = "data:image/png;" + event.data;
```

Assuming `event.data` is the actual data as a string.